# How to setup a project that uses a lib but should not support all of its localizations?

Tags: android, localization

I have the following structure:

1. a library project LIB with languages A,B,C
2. an app project P1 using the LIB - which is available in languages A,B,C so for this I just create an empty project P1 which is based on the LIB project
3. another app project P2 also using LIB  - which should be available in languages A,B,C this is a different branded version than P1 which does not use all LIB functions
4. now I need to make another app project P3 based on LIB but should only be available in a new language D

**How can I setup P3 using LIB so languages A,B,C are not available to P3 but only a new language D?**

Naturally I like to avoid putting the language ressources for A,B,C directly into P1 an P2 instead of LIB, since all language ressources would have to be copied and maintained in 2 different places

Comment: Don't code format something which is not code !

Answer (score 0):

You can create your P3 project as usual and create the language resources inside it. That way P3 will be using its internal resources for the language. However I don't think that is possible languages A,B,C not to be available to P3 since android's libraries resources are merged with project resources.

A possible solution is to move your languages A,B,C in a separate library from LIB for example LANGLIB and reference it from your P1 and P2 but not from P3. So by doing this you will have:

P1 + LIB + LANGLIB, P2 + LIB + LANGLIB, P3(with language D inside it) + LIB.

Hope this helps...